# Python TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable Error

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am mere a beginner of Python. I am getting the following error and suspect that it has something to do with the dictionary I've used as switch case (since python does not provide switch ). Following is my code:

```
class Arithmetic:

    a,b,choice = 0,0,0


    def __init__(self):

        print "\n\n"

        for num in range(30):
            print "*",

        print "\n"    

        print "Welcome to CLC (Command Line Calculator)"

        print "\n"

        for num in range(30):
            print "*",

        print "\n"

    def menu(self):

        print "1. Add"
        print "2. Substract"
        print "3. Multiply"
        print "4. Divide"
        print "5. Modulo"
        print "6. Exit \n\n"

        self.choice = raw_input("Enter Your Choice: ")

        if self.choice == '0':
            exit("Thank you for using the program")

        selector = {
                "1" :   self.add(),
                "2" :   self.substract(), 
                "3" :   self.multiply(),
                "4" :   self.divide(),
                "5" :   self.modulo()
                }

        selector[self.choice]()                    

    def add(self):
        print "Add called"

    def substract(self):
        print "Substract called"

    def multiply(self):
        print "Multiply called"

    def divide(self):
        print "Divide called"

    def modulo(self):
        print "Modulo called"


    def main(self):

        while self.choice != '6':
            self.menu()   



a = Arithmetic()
a.menu()
```

The Error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "arithmetics.py", line 75, in <module>
a.menu()
File "arithmetics.py", line 43, in menu
  selector[self.choice]()                    
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: plz also paste your traceback info to make the error clear ;)

Comment: remove the `()` in the selector dict: you want the name of the function, not calling it.

Comment: oops! :D I have will edit the question right away!

Comment: Yes, you are adding the value returned by the functions rather than the functions to selected. Also, what happens if the user enters `6`? Or indeed any value other than 1 to 5?

Comment: Your functions return `None` because they lack a `return` statement. Two many bugs in your code, you should learn step-by-step, not just write down a program and then see what happens.

Comment: You should have a look at [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html), which implements these for you.

Comment: I just do not understand why am I being down voted!! Will any one please explain?

Answer (score 3):

When you do

```
self.add()
```

you are calling the method (you will get a result). If you want to specify the method, delete the `()`:

```
selector = {
            "1" :   self.add,
            "2" :   self.substract, 
            "3" :   self.multiply,
            "4" :   self.divide,
            "5" :   self.modulo
            }
```

Comment: You're the Rain maker !! :D

Answer (score 1):

replace this :

```
selector[self.choice]()
```

to:

```
selector[self.choice]
```

demo:

```
>>> def test():
...     return "hello"
... 
>>> my_dict = {1:test()}
>>> my_dict[1]
'hello'
```

Comment: Won't work in the OP example, where the functions are actually interesting because of side-effects (print statements), not return values.  In this case, the dict really does need to store the function, and code needs to retrieve the function object and run it, rather than have the dict store the return values of the functions and throw them back.

Comment: @zehnpaard for your kind information its going to work

Comment: downvoters add comment with  your genuine reason

Comment: perhaps I'm misunderstanding your point, but OP's example has a print statement and no return in his functions.  Will your example work if the `test()` function also only had a print statement?

Comment: yes it will work, in my demo example replace return with print and see you will get it, give it a try :)

Comment: I get 'hello' printed *when I add the entry to the dict*, and nothing gets printed when I access the entry via `my_dict[0]`.  Running `my_dict` shows `{1:None}`.